# COUNT OF in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

I only want the count of Brands (Blue, White, Red) if their corresponding Customer value is listed more than once.

```
  *customer*  *productid*   *brand*
      1            A          Red       
      2            B          Blue
      1            A          Red
      2            C          Blue
      3            B          White
      1            A          Red
      2            B          Blue
```

Desired result: I want a single dataset that has the Brands with their tallied count, only for Customers that are repeat purchasers.

```
  *brands*    *repeat_purchase*
    Red              3
    Blue             2
```

```
select customer, productid, count(productid) as repeat_purchase
from Public."CustomerData"
group by customer, productid
having count(productid) > 1;
```

Above is what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to get just two columns: One with the name of each Brand, and one with the total number of times a that each brand is included in a repeat purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to want two levels of aggregation:

```
select brand, sum(cnt)
from (select customer, product, brand, count(*) as cnt
      from Public."CustomerData"
      group by customer, product, brand
      having count(*) >= 2
     ) t
group by brand;
```